# Ruby (Rails) string manipulation upon create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

I'm working on a twitter-like app for practice. Users create posts, and I'm adding functionality so that users can tag other users in their posts by putting @email of the user they want to tag at the beginning of their post.

in_reply_to is the id of the user being tagged in the Micropost.

This is in my Micropost_controller.rb

```
@reply_regex = /(\A@[^@ ]+(@)\w+(\.[a-z]{2,3}){1,2}.*\z)/i
def create
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
  if @micropost.content =~ @reply_regex
    email = @micropost.content.scan(/([^@ ]+(@)\w+(\.[a-z]{2,3}){1,2})/i).first.first
    @micropost.in_reply_to = User.find_by_email(email).id
  end
  if @micropost.save 
    flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
    redirect_to root_path
```

When I run the email-extracting part on a string in the console it works perfectly and returns the email. But when I create new microposts, the in_reply_to always stays nil.

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Comment: how is the user entering his post? If it is a rich editor you are likely to get HTML in the param. Try to log @micropost.content to see what it contains. Just a space in the beginning would ruin your logic as it is now.

Comment: @froderik: It doesn't matter what `@micropost.content` contains, `@reply_regex` will be `nil` and `x =~ nil` will be false.

Comment: ouch - my eyes are bleeding. thanks for correcting my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
class C
  @a = 11
end
```

does **not** create an instance variable named `@a` for instances of `C`. When you hit `@a = 11`, `self` will be the class itself so `@a` will be an instance variable for the the object `C`. If you put the above into `irb` and look at [`C.instance_variables`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-instance_variables), you will see this:

```
>> C.instance_variables
=> [:a]
```

but when you look at an instance of `C`:

```
>> C.new.instance_variables
=> []
```

Also, instance variables are automatically created on first use and initialized to be `nil`.

Combining the above tells us that you have a `@reply_regex` instance variable in the **class** object `MicropostController` but not in the instances. Your `def create` is an instance method so it will use the `@reply_regex` instance variable; but you don't have `@reply_regex` as an instance variable for `MicropostController` objects so it will be created and initialized as `nil` inside your `if` statement. The result is that your `if` ends up being this:

```
if @micropost.content =~ nil
```

and `@micropost.content =~ nil` will evaluate to `nil` and, since `nil` is false in a boolean context, the `if` block is never entered and `@micropost.in_reply_to` is never assigned a value.

You can use a class variable for your regex:

```
@@reply_regex = /(\A@[^@ ]+(@)\w+(\.[a-z]{2,3}){1,2}.*\z)/i
def create
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
  if @micropost.content =~ @@reply_regex
    #...
```

as class variables are visible to instance methods or, better, just use a constant:

```
REPLY_REGEX = /(\A@[^@ ]+(@)\w+(\.[a-z]{2,3}){1,2}.*\z)/i
def create
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
  if @micropost.content =~ REPLY_REGEX
    #...
```

As an aside, I think you should move the reply-to checking into your model. You could use a `before_validation` callback to strip off any leading and trailing whitespace in `content` and extract and save the reply-to:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validate :process_content, :if => :content_changed?
  #...
  private
  def process_content
    # Strip leading/trailing whitespace from self.content
    # Extract the reply-to from self.content and save it in self.in_reply_to
  end
end
```

The advantage here is that if the content is changed or created without going through your controller (such as a migration, by hand in the Rails console, some system task that is notifying the users of something, ...), you still get everything done.